# How to install vue-router 4 in vue ^2.6.14 version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Hi i have a requirement  to use `vue-router4` on `vue:^2.6.14` app because i want to use the latest api regarding dynamically registering a route.

**Problem:** i tried to move `vue:^2.6.14` app to `vue:3.*.*` as there is a requirement of using new `vue-router` api which supports https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/dynamic-routing.html#adding-nested-routes   based on that i asked a question which is un-answered [Dynamically registered route is not working when it is just pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686564/dynamically-registered-route-is-not-working-when-it-is-just-pushed)

**Note:** i tried for complete migration but facing so many errors

**My Expection:** i want to use `vue-router@4` in `vue:^2.6.14` only for `addRoute('parent',{...Route Object}) method` https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/dynamic-routing.html#adding-routes if overriding is possible to get this feature in `vue-router3` for `vue2` then it is most welcomed!

**Note2:** after overriding it should work as this example https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-test-hvzes5?file=/src/main.js , Note: in `main.js` only 2 routes are defined.

**Issue with vue-router3 for vue2**: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1156

Please help me thanks in advance !!

Comment: @tony19 is there any extra helper package to use `vue-router@4` with `vue@2`. please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to use `vue-router@4` with `vue@2`. They're incompatible with each other.

And the question assumes that `addRoute` is only available in `vue-router@4`, but that's not true. [`addRoute()`](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroute) was introduced in `vue-router@3.5.0`, which *is* compatible with `vue@2`.

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686564/dynamically-registered-route-is-not-working-when-it-is-just-pushed), I think the confusion might be caused by the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832181/dynamically-add-child-routes-in-vuejs/48833074#48833074), which only applies to **`vue-router@2`**, which does not support `addRoute`. The workaround provided in that answer would not work properly with `vue-router@3`, as you had observed.

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-adding-routes-in-vue-2-ootee6?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) of your Codesandbox written in `vue@2.6.14` with `vue-router@3.5.4`. Your original code to dynamically add routes was untouched.

Comment: Is there vue router compatible version for Vue 2.7.*?

Comment: @PeterVasilev `vue-router@3` should work with `vue@2`.